# Start service from service

Tags: android

I have a service in my application but this service stop working after time and i want to keep the service keep working without stopping and for that i try to start the same service from onDestroy method when it dieing but its not work even the written log not appear ,so  it is possible to call the service from itself and if it  not may i create another service who do the same work and they call each other when one of them stopped, so when in onDestory i cant call it so how to call it?, wish that someone can help me with this situation thnx on advance

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to start the service again yourself. Better return START_STICKY or START_REDELIVER_INTENT from onStartCommand() and the system will do it for you when it has enough resources.

See the following link where there is also an example.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: im also using it, but  the problem that is the services is running in the setting and when i check if the service running its return true but its not working may it sleeping or something so how i can awake it ?

Comment: In this case I believe your service is fine and the problem lies somewhere in the actual implementation. Without some code from your service to see how you test for its state there is not much to say.